# java applet cmd+shift mac osx

Tags: java, macos, swing, applet

On mac osx, if you run a java applet in the browser, It's possible to pop the applet out of the browser by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>. This is actually a workaround given for when you want to drag and drop something inside your applet - the drag and drop in an applet inside the browser is broken on mac osx.

So my question is, there is any way I can check if the applet is out of the browser using Java? Any of you have any idea?

**Edit:**
This <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> functionality to detach the frame out of the browser is broken on JRE 7 as well as the drag and drop.

Comment: How does the D-n-D fail?  Does it throw Exceptions?

Comment: Just an experiment, but you could try to locate the root window containing the applet, either by iterating over parent links yourself or using `SwingUtilities.getRoot` or `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor`. With a bit of luck, the class name of that window, or some other property of it, will give you an indication you can use.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2011/Jul/msg00083.html

Comment: On mac osx and when using the normal java TransferHandler the drag and drop is just ignore, once the applet is running on the browser. No exceptions in the java trace.
Is this enough for you? If not, I can sen you a small example so you can run it on mac to see the behavior.

Comment: @MvG: Thanks for your comment. Your idea seem to work. Maybe you should create a reply so I can accept it...

Comment: I did create an answer, but feel free to write an answer yourself, including the actual method you used, and the actual value you use to distinguish the situations. Don't worry about the acceptance rep, as long as you upvote my answer as well I'll be happy enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer.*

You could try to locate the root window containing the applet, either by iterating over [parent links](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getParent%28%29) yourself or using [`SwingUtilities.getRoot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getRoot%28java.awt.Component%29) or [`SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor%28java.awt.Component%29). With a bit of luck, the class name of that window, or some other property of it, will give you an indication you can use.

Comment: When the applet run inside the browser, SwingUtilities.getRoot(c) will return an object type PluginEmbeddedFrameCALayer. When running as a floating frame, the type of the root component is DetachedAppletController$DetachFrame.